# Android C++ application crashes in linking to shared library stage

Tags: android, c++, crash

I have a hello world C++ application that links with many 3rdpart and home-made libraries. It crashes immediately when trying to load it, with Segmentation Fault.
The same code, with the same dependencies, all compiled for Linux - runs successfully.

How can I start to debug it?
What could be the reason?

Edit: This is what logcat prints:

```
F/libc    ( 8129): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 128, fault addr 0x0 in tid 8129 (HelloWorldApp) I/DEBUG   ( 2876): *** *** *** *** *** ***
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** I/DEBUG   ( 2876): Build fingerprint: 'Intel/cht_hr/cht_hr:5.1.1/LMY47Z/LS0000037:userdebug/test-keys' I/DEBUG   ( 2876): Revision: '0' W/NativeCrashListener( 3194): Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 8129 I/DEBUG   ( 2876): ABI: 'x86' I/DEBUG   ( 2876): pid: 8129, tid: 8129, name: HelloWorldApp  >>> ./StaticImageOR <<< E/DEBUG   ( 2876): AM write failure (32 / Broken pipe) I/DEBUG   ( 2876): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 128 (SI_KERNEL), fault addr 0x0 I/DEBUG   ( 2876):     eax ff84cadc  ebx f32b7c6c  ecx 00000010  edx 00000000 I/DEBUG   ( 2876):     esi f32c6610  edi 00000000 I/DEBUG   ( 2876):     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000002b I/DEBUG   ( 2876):     eip f2600cfb  ebp ff84c6dc  esp ff84c5f4  flags 00010246 I/DEBUG   ( 2876):  I/DEBUG   ( 2876): backtrace: I/DEBUG   ( 2876):     #00 pc 0062fcfb  /system/lib/libcommander.so I/DEBUG   ( 2876):     #01 pc 0017651f  /system/lib/libcommander.so I/DEBUG   ( 2876):     #02 pc 00001fcb  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfo16CallConstructorsEv.part.23+1275) I/DEBUG   ( 2876): 
#03 pc 00001c26  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfo16CallConstructorsEv.part.23+342) I/DEBUG   ( 2876):  
#04 pc 00001c26  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfo16CallConstructorsEv.part.23+342) I/DEBUG   ( 2876):  
#05 pc 00008706  /system/bin/linker (__dl___linker_init+4998) I/DEBUG   ( 2876):     #06 pc 00009e0e  /system/bin/linker (__dl__start+30) I/DEBUG   ( 2876):  I/DEBUG   ( 2876): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
```

So I undersatnd the problem is in libcommander loading.
How to continue with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Run in a debugger using the emulator? It could be any one of thousands of reasons.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That is exactly my question: how can I debug it?

Comment: Android is a lockeddown subset API (C and C++) so maybe your libraries are calling functions that don't exist (or are restricted) in the Android C/C++ libs.  As libcomander is for comandline processing is your device rooted?

Comment: @RichardCritten: libcommander isn't for command line utils. This is an internal library. Thanks!

Comment: @Becky_R it's loading it from /system/lib - are you building your own Android image?

Comment: @RichardCritten: I used adb push to push this library to /system/lib.

Comment: why are you pushing it to /system/lib ? it should be put into you apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to run your application under debugger, then most recent android studio is really good at debugging c++ code. For instructions how to debug jni code, find Create Hello-JNI with Android Studio in [google code labs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/).

Other solution is to look into logcat, you might find there reason for the crash. For example you can find lines like

```
I/DEBUG   ( 8704): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad
...
...
```

which will contain call stack for the location where crash happend. With that information you can use `ndk-stack` - tool (see here [ndk-stack](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html)), to turn frame addresses into symbolic names.

Android will put into logcat other warnings/jni error that might help you find a location of the problem.